# how to configure mongo to store the db in specific path before installation -ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

My app is running on a separate docker container

How can I configure mongo dbPath when I install mongoDB on the app docker?
or should I do it with mongo command `mongod --dbpat [PATH]` and then update mongo.conf file?

another question- I'm using node express app to connect the monodb throue mongoose,
will it automatically connect to the new db path?
connect to db code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/DB_NAME', {
    promiseLibrary: require('bluebird'),
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, If you started mongodb with dbpath then you database & collections will be created that path only.

Comment: ok, so I don't need to edit the mongo.conf file for that?

Comment: no need to edit config file but always make sure to  start mongodb service with same dbpath